# linkedin and onLinkedInLoad

Tags: javascript, linkedin-api

I have the possibility of LinkedIn login to my website, to postulate for a job. . I followed the tutorial given on the LinkedIn developer page, this is my code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
    api_key:   [...]
    lang:      fr_FR
    authorize: false
    onLoad: onLinkedInLoad
</script>


<script type="text/javascript">

// Setup an event listener to make an API call once auth is complete
function onLinkedInLoad() {
    IN.Event.on(IN, "auth", getProfileData);
}

// Handle the successful return from the API call
function onSuccess(data) {
    console.log(data);
}

// Handle an error response from the API call
function onError(error) {
    console.log(error);
}

  function getProfileData(){
   [...]    
}
 </script>
```

The login button appears, this means that LinkedIn was able to connect to my API key correctly, but the Chrome console gives me the following error: Uncaught Error: Could not execute 'onLinkedInLoad'. Please provide a valid function for callback..

I tried to remove the onLinkedInLoad event listener :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     IN.Event.on(IN, "auth", getProfileData);

 [...]

</script>
```

... but i have the same problem.

Theses scripts are called in head (php include of all pages of the website (i need this linkedin login on all pages)).

It works on ONE page, but not on the others... i don't understand.

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Need to below script available for all pages where you want login button. if you are putting this script on particular page then lgoin button will work on that page only.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
    api_key:   [...]
    lang:      fr_FR
    authorize: false
    onLoad: onLinkedInLoad
</script>
```